How to programmatically set KDE Plasma desktop wallpaper to a colour?
Like this similar question about image wallpapers asks:

How do I set the KDE desktop wallpaper to a .JPEG file from the command line?

...except that I want to set it to a colour rather than an image, as:












...allows.
Relevant

I ask because https://github.com/oskarsh/Yin-Yang/issues/246#issuecomment-1837211935 hasn't been implemented.

Transferred to here from superuser.com per this comment by a moderator regarding a request to transfer it:

Regarding your flag to migrate this question is too old. We cannot migrate questions older than 6 months. You are free to re-ask it on Unix & Linux yourself.




Per https://discuss.kde.org/t/how-to-set-wallpaper-background-color-in-command-line/10645?u=rokejulianlockhart, this doesn't appear to be possible, yet.
